# Problem with ggplot - not visualizing my y variable correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a simple graph of Apple's forward PE ratio over the last 10 years. My data is

| year | forward PE |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 27.40 |
| 2020 | 30.12 |
| 2019 | 17.27 |
| 2018 | 16.69 |
| 2017 | 14.24 |
| 2016 | 12.66 |
| 2015 | 11.04 |
| 2014 | 13.79 |
| 2013 | 10.81 |
| 2012 | 13.00 |
| 2011 | 11.57 |

File name is PE and my code is:

```
ggplot(PE, aes(x=year, y='forward PE')) +
    geom_point()
```

This is what I'm getting back:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkkul.png)

The y variable is showing up as a horizontal line. Is there anyway to fix this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to backquote the column there is a space in the column (instead of single or double quote)

```
ggplot(PE, aes(x=year, y=`forward PE`)) +
    geom_point() + 
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(.data[["forward PE"]][1:5])))
```

-outut
[image]

---

Or if we want to pass strings, extract with `.data`

```
ggplot(PE, aes(x=year, y= .data[["forward PE"]])) +
     geom_point()
```

#### data

```
PE <- structure(list(year = 2021:2011, `forward PE` = c(27.4, 30.12, 
17.27, 16.69, 14.24, 12.66, 11.04, 13.79, 10.81, 13, 11.57)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! I will keep this in mind in the future. I had another quick question if it's not too much trouble, otherwise don't worry about it. If I wanted to add the forward PE's 5-year average (21) as a horizontal line on top of the graph, is that something ggplot can do?

Comment: How id you get 21 as average.  I tried `mean(PE[[2]][1:5])
[1] 16.144` and the whole data as `mean(PE[[2]])#
[1] 13.96273`

Comment: @ akrun Sorry the 1st row has a typo and should be 27.4, not 2.4.